# Make: super ignore errors

Tags: makefile

If I want to run a command that may or may not work, depending on the situation, I add a dash

```
make-rule:
   -command that may fail
```

however, when this command fails, I get a message that the entire recipe failed.

How do I flag the command as totally optional, such that even if it fails, make just notes that it failed, but not that the over-all recipe failed?

(this saves time having to carefully read the make messages, if I don't get informed that the entire recipe failed)

Comment: I don't understand: if the line is prefixed with `-` then you won't get a message that the entire recipe failed.  You'll get a message that that specific line failed, and make will tell you it ignored the failure, and it will run the rest of the recipe and complete with a success code.  If you don't even want to see the message, definitely Virgile's answer is a good one.

Comment: @MadScientist I was actually getting recipe failed messages **in addition** to that message which you are describing; i will double check and get back to you if I find a chance.

Comment: I tried it and it worked as expected for me.  Formatting in SO comments is not possible but I just had a rule `all:` with the first recipe line `-false` and the second recipe line `true`.

Comment: @MadScientist sounds like something else may be going on.  I will double check what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit manual, but you can use an or-sequence in the recipe, as in:

```
make-rule:
    command that may fail || echo "command failed with status $$?"
```

since `echo` will succeed, `make` will consider that the whole line is OK, but you still get your error message in case of problem.